# Show a form when REQUEST_METHOD is GET in PHP

Tags: php, forms

How do you show the form only when the method is get? I've tried using isset, but ended up confusing myself more. I've come up with the following code that seems to be the simplest way to do it, but it doesn't work for some reason

```
<html>
<?php 
if ($_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD"]=="GET") {

}else {
    die( 'Invalid Method.');
}

?>

<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <select name="state">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    </select>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It just prints "Invalid Method" after clicking submit.

*Edit: made a mistake in the original code. Error occurs after hitting submit.

Comment: A lot wrong with the way you are doing things, but without going down rabbit holes, the reason you are getting `Invalid Method.` is because you are doing `$_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD"]!="GET"` when it should be `$_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD"]=="GET"`

Comment: My mistake, I was trying other ways and forgot to change it back. The error occurs after clicking submit.

Comment: That's because submitting POSTs the form, so after submitting, `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` will be `"POST"`. Ergo, `!= "GET"`, therefore it will die with an 'Invalid Method' message.

Answer (score 1):

You viewed your page in your browser which means you used GET method.

> $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD"]

returned "GET" which is not different from "GET" and 'else' is fired.

Answer (score 0):

try the !== operator. And you don't need to use the action attribute avec the default value is PHP_SELF :)

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD"] !== "GET") {
     exit('Invalid Method.');
}else {

}

?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" >
    <select name="state">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    </select>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```